# When is 'Article Date' populated?

Tags: column, publishing-page, date-time

I'm looking at different date fields of a Page I can use and have noticed there's an Article Date column under Publishing Columns. At what point is this column populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand your question.  Just like all of the publishing fields for a page layout, when you create a new page you fill out the data on that page, the article date being on of those fields.

Comment: So it's not automatically populated (just as a modified date would be for example)? +1.

Comment: No, it's a field you fill out.  You can set a default value on it I believe but it is not the same as modified date.